# merging two files according to a common column

Tags: text-processing, awk, join, bioinformatics

I have 2 files. File1 is:

```
chr19   4124051 4124250 1
chrX    154458151   154458200   2
chr22   37019451    37019600    3
chr15   74995401    74995550    4
chr12   128823901   128824100   5
```

and File2 is:

```
chr19   4124051 4124250 1   CUP
chr15   74995401    74995550    4   CUP
chr12   128823901   128824100   5   CUP
chr12   122752651   122752950   8   CUP
chr13   113297001   113297350   9   CUP
```

and I would like to have a File3 like this:

```
chr19   4124051 4124250 1 CUP
chrX    154458151   154458200   2
chr22   37019451    37019600    3
chr15   74995401    74995550    4 CUP
chr12   128823901   128824100   5 CUP
```

I'd like to merge the two files according to column 4 of File1, and adding values of column 5 from File2 to the last column of File1 whenever there is a match.

I tired this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4]=$5;next} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,a[$4]}' File2 File1 > file3
```

but it didn't work, it creates an extra row under each row.

And I tried join command as well:

```
join -1 4 -2 4 -o'1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.5' File1 File2
```

and it creates an empty file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your awk command should work perfectly. Are these files coming from Windows by any chance? What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using a Mac, and using the bash terminal . The files came from Excel actually, I saved them in Windows Formatted text. I don't know if it's a problem of formatting actually ..

Comment: It is. If the file came from excel, the problem is precisely that. You need to remove the Windows-style line endings.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance eheh but I have no idea how to do it :( do I have to save it in another format then?

Comment: See my answer below. Just run the `sed` commands first to remove the `\r` and then your other approaches should work as expected. By the way: please don't use Excel for bioinformatics analyses! Every time you do, you make a bioinformatician cry :P

Comment: Eheheh I imagine, and will remember your advice! I am starting not to use excel, I promise I'll keep on trying! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your files were created in Windows so they have Windows style line-endings (`\r\n`). Remove the `\r` and everything should work as you expect:

```
sed -i 's/\r//' File1
sed -i 's/\r//' File2
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4]=$5;next} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,a[$4]}' File2 File1 > file3
```

Answer (score 1):

***join*** + ***sort*** solution:

```
join -j4 -a1 -o1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.5 <(sort -k4 File1) <(sort -k4 File2) | column -t
```

The output:

```
chr19  4124051    4124250    1  CUP
chrX   154458151  154458200  2
chr22  37019451   37019600   3
chr15  74995401   74995550   4  CUP
chr12  128823901  128824100  5  CUP
```

---

- `-j4` - join by the 4th column
- `-a1` - print unpairable lines from the 1st file
- `sort -k4 File1` - sort the file via 4th column/key (`-k4`)

Comment: Thanks! but it doesn't work either .. It finds only a match in the last row, while the matching fields are the 80% of the list.. Could be a problem of the input file? Not correctly formatted or tabulated .. it comes from excel originally.

Comment: @Chiara, yes, I think there are issues with whitespaces in your file. Try to apply `sed -i 's/ *$|\r//' file` to your file beforehand

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F'\s+' -lane '
   s/\r$//; my $i = join $;, @F[0,3];
   @ARGV and $h{$i} = $F[4],next;
   print exists $h{$i} ? s/$/ $h{$i}/r : $_;
' File2 File1
```

Gives:

```
chr19   4124051 4124250 1
chrX    154458151   154458200   2
chr22   37019451    37019600    3
chr15   74995401    74995550    4 CUP
chr12   128823901   128824100   5 CUP
```